# Django allauth - no verification email for social users

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I am using Django allauth for my website's auth needs.

When a user signs up to my site with a social account - Google mostly (I've got only twitter, facebook and google set up, mostly the users seem to prefer google) - the user's email is *always* auto-verified, that is despite these settings from the allauth documentation (http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#configuration) being set :

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
```

*No* verification email is *ever* sent for an account that signs up via Social and the email is always listed as "verified" despite that.

I've got an important security hook set up to intercept on a verification signal. I *need* the social users to get the email and click the email verification link.

Users who sign up manually all work fine (email, verification link, etc).

What is or could be wrong?

Python 3.3, Django 1.6.2, django-allauth 0.15.0 (via pip)

Update: Even if I set

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = False
```

and force the user to fill in the form, it still auto-verifies social users.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google signups are automatically verified because Google certifies that the email address is verified. Try logging in with Twitter and you'll see that verification does kick in, but only when really needed.

Comment: Yes I saw that this morning when someone used a twitter account to sign up. Thanks.